# Cloudinary Search API Expression [Python]

Tags: cloudinary

I've been trying use the search api, but I've been receiving a correct answer.
I've been looking for a folder and the name of the folder is something like:

"travel_to_rome_12345"

and I'm using the search expression:

"travel AND to AND rome AND 12345"

but I receive this as answer : {'total_count': 0, 'time': 4, 'resources': []} .
But there are resources in the folder. How could I search this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are there additional details that would warrant a use case such as this? For example, if you wanted to search the "travel_to_rome_12345" folder, you should search for exactly that string. If you have multiple folders that you'd like to search, say "travel_to_rome_12345" and "travel_to_england_54321" you have a few options.

First, you could tag the assets in certain folders so that you could search by tag instead. In this example you might consider a "travel" tag. For more information on adding tags to assets, please see here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520142-How-can-I-tag-an-image-

Second, if the folders in question have a similar naming convention, you could search for "travel*" to find all assets that have "travel" as the prefix in the folders that contain them.